# Unable to check text field entry using Robot Framework

Tags: angularjs, robotframework, robotframework-ide

I am a newbie to Robot Framework, I am trying to check if my text field contains the correct entry.

[image: Text Fields Image]

As you can see in the above screenshot, I have South Boston in one of my address fields. The html for this is:

```
<input id="profileDeliveryAddressAddress2" class="small ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched" type="text" ng-model="user.delivery_address.address1" maxlength="30" aria-invalid="false"></div>
```

I have tried the following to check for the text South Boston.

Method1:

```
${addressText}    Get Text   id=profileDeliveryAddressAddress2
Should Be Equal As Strings    ${addressText}    South Boston
```

Method 2

```
${addressText}    Get Value  id=profileDeliveryAddressAddress2
Should Be Equal As Strings    ${addressText}    South Boston
```

Method 3

```
${expected_text}      South Boston
${addressText}=       Get Value    id=profileDeliveryAddressAddress2
Should Be Equal    ${search text}    ${addressText}
```

Method 4

```
${expected_text}      South Boston 
${addressText}=       Get Text    id=profileDeliveryAddressAddress2
Should Be Equal    ${search text}    ${addressText}
```

However none of these methods work. Can someone please help me out with what I am doing wrong, or perhaps suggest a new method?

I am able to input text into the field using the ID, so Robot is finding the element at least.

Comment: When asking a question and facing difficulties, please describe what you observe. A comment like ".. none of these methods work" doesn't provide any details on what might be the matter. Ex python itself, Robot Framework, your external module or your script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured this out. Used the following:

```
Textfield Value Should Be    id=profileDeliveryAddressAddress2    South Boston
```